# unable to convert nested json to flat json using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

i have a  dynamic json like below in the nested json structure

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "_score": 0.5753642,
      "_type": "data",
      "_id": "686",
      "_source": {
        "mainData": "subset",
        "data": "vehicle",
        "name": "subset_vehicle",
        "fields": [
          "number",
          "id",
          "chasis"
        ],
        "dataset": "chasis"
      },
      "_index": "vehicle"
    },
   {
      "_score": 0.575,
      "_type": "data",
      "_id": "687",
      "_source": {
        "mainData": "subset1",
        "data": "vehicle1",
        "name": "subset_vehicle1",
        "fields": [
          "number",
          "id",
          "chasis"
        ],
        "dataset": "chasis1"
      },
      "_index": "vehicle"
    },
    {
      "_score": 0.57,
      "_type": "data",
      "_id": "686",
      "_source": {
        "mainData": "subset",
        "data": "vehicle",
        "name": "subset_vehicle",
        "fields": [
          "number",
          "id",
          "chasis"
        ],
        "dataset": "chasis"
      },
      "_index": "vehicle"
    }
  ]

}
```

and  i want to convert it as flat json kind off

```
{
    "_id": "686",
     "mainData": "subset",
    "data": "vehicle",
    "dataset": "chasis"
    "name": "subset_vehicle",
    "fields": [
      "number",
      "id",
      "chasis"
    ]
}
```

so when ever i click on the id on the front end side based on that id particular object has to be converted like the above i mean flat json . i used to below logic to convert

```
var flatArray = [];
var flatObject = {};

for (var index = 0; index < data.length; index++) {
  for (var prop in data[index]) {

    var value = data[index][prop];

    if (Array.isArray(value)) {
      for (var i = 0; i < value.length; i++) {
        for (var inProp in value[i]) {
          flatObject[inProp] = value[i][inProp];
        }
      }
    }else{
        flatObject[prop] = value;
    }
  }
  flatArray.push(flatObject);
}

console.log(flatArray);
```

but i unable to convert it

Answer (score 5):

You can simply us `Array.flatMap()` or `Array.map()` methods to return a new array. As per your requirement, both will work. [Array.flatMap()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap) & [Array.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

```js
var data = [{"_score":0.5753642,"_type":"data","_id":"686","_source":{"mainData":"subset","data":"vehicle","name":"subset_vehicle","fields":["number","id","chasis"],"dataset":"chasis"},"_index":"vehicle"},{"_score":0.575,"_type":"data","_id":"687","_source":{"mainData":"subset1","data":"vehicle1","name":"subset_vehicle1","fields":["number","id","chasis"],"dataset":"chasis1"},"_index":"vehicle"},{"_score":0.57,"_type":"data","_id":"686","_source":{"mainData":"subset","data":"vehicle","name":"subset_vehicle","fields":["number","id","chasis"],"dataset":"chasis"},"_index":"vehicle"}]

var a = data.flatMap(d => {
  d._source._id = d._id;
  return d._source;
})

console.log(a)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use object spread syntax for that:

```js
const data = [{"_score": 0.5753642,"_type": "data","_id": "686","_source": {"mainData": "subset","data": "vehicle","name": "subset_vehicle","fields": ["number","id","chasis"],"dataset": "chasis"},"_index": "vehicle"},{"_score": 0.575,"_type": "data","_id": "687","_source": {"mainData": "subset1","data": "vehicle1","name": "subset_vehicle1","fields": ["number","id","chasis"],"dataset": "chasis1"},"_index": "vehicle"},{"_score": 0.57,"_type": "data","_id": "686","_source": {"mainData": "subset","data": "vehicle","name": "subset_vehicle","fields": ["number","id","chasis"],"dataset": "chasis"},"_index": "vehicle"}];

const flatArray = data.map(({_id, _source}) => ({ _id, ..._source }));
console.log(flatArray);
```